# How can you add html layers to Polymaps?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have just started using [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org) and am finding the API a little advanced. I have managed to work out how to overlay basic images onto a map, but was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to overlay html elements that can be styled with css.

**My end goal is to overlay users' avatar pictures with a little CSS styling onto their location on a Polymap.**

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I've asked for help on a similar question at the GIS Stack Exchange.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27667/polymaps-marker-point-popup

But I think an answer might be towards the end of this blog post
http://thinkwhere.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/pubs-in-england-how-to-do-it-with-polymaps-and-geocommons-filters/

Comment: Link only answers are better than no answers at all. The examples on the link page at least show how to address the problem.